# How to fill data set using multiple tables?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql, database, vb.net

`SELECT dbo.Tbl_Employees.User_Name, dbo.Tbl_Employees.Project_ID, dbo.Tbl_Project.Project
FROM  dbo.Tbl_Employees INNER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Project ON dbo.Tbl_Employees.Project_ID=dbo.Tbl_Project.Project_ID`

This is my query, How should i fill the dataset with data adapter When i have two tables.
Please give some inputs

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could start by having a look at

[DataAdapter.Fill Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[DataAdapter.Fill Method (DataSet)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377a8x4t.aspx)

Even [Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx#Y0)

Answer (score 0):

Because your **SqlDataAdapter** works in disconnected mode you do not have to provide a SqlConnection to fill the **DataTable**

```
 string query ="SELECT dbo.Tbl_Employees.User_Name, dbo.Tbl_Employees.Project_ID, dbo.Tbl_Project.Project FROM dbo.Tbl_Employees INNER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Project ON dbo.Tbl_Employees.Project_ID=dbo.Tbl_Project.Project_ID"

Dim ds = new DataSet()
Dim da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, ConnectionString)

   try{ 
     da.Fill(ds);
     }
     catch(Excepion ex){

    }
```

**Update:**
If you need to show all the data contained in the dataset just pass in the **DS** as datasource for the Gridview or if you need just the records from the first table pass in **DS.Tables(0)** as datasource to the control.

```
   If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then 
   GridView2.DataSource = ds 
   GridView2.DataBind()
```

Comment: If Ds.Tables("*******").Rows.Count > 0 Then

            GridView2.DataSource = Ds
            GridView2.DataBind()   in the ***** which table i have to mention since i have two .

Comment: @karthikgorijavolu If Ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then GridView2.DataSource = Ds.Tables(0)  GridView2.DataBind()

Comment: adpt.Fill(Ds) is this ok or adt.fill(ds,table(0),table(1)) have to be mentioned?

Comment: @karthikgorijavolu adat.Fill(DS) or event use this adat.Fill(DS.Tables(0)) or adat.Fill(DS,"Table0") I hope this can help

Comment: Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: @karthikgorijavolu is hard to guess why you're getting this exception, please post your code.